# Lsyncd 2.2.2 ownership and permission issue (rsync, centos 7)

Tags: rsync

I'm having an issue where files are been copied to the remote server except the owner/group of replicated files on the target server is always '1002'. The permissions of the source are respected and replicated correctly on the target. I just can't figure out a way to preserve the owner (and group) of the replicated files.

Lsyncd Version: 2.2.2

my setting below:

```
settings {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
}

sync {
    default.rsyncssh,
    source="/home",
    host="1*52.*.15",
    targetdir="/home/",
    delete = "running", -- prevents deletion of files on startup (ie when a server comes back online, don't delete files that are new on the backup)
    delay = 5, -- run every 5 seconds instead of default 20
    exclude = {
        "/home/backup",
    },
    rsync = {
        archive = true, -- use the archive flag in rsync
        perms = true, -- Keep the permissions
        owner = true, -- Keep the owner
        compress = true,
        acls = true,
            xattrs = true,
        _extra = {"-a"}, -- Sometimes permissions and owners isn't copied correctly so the _extra can be used for any flag in rsync
    }
}
```